# Excel table to 'details view'

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, vba

I have a table in Excel like this

```
Column1  Column2  Column3
Value1A  Value2A  Value3A
Value1B  Value2B  Value3B
Value1C  Value2C  Value3C
```

I want to convert to a 'details view' in word like this:

```
Column1: Value1A 
Column2: Value1B 
Column3: Value1C 

Column1: Value2A 
Column2: Value2B 
Column3: Value2C 

Column1: Value3A
Column2: Value3B
Column3: Value3C
```

Any advice?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. Source: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Was wondering if there are any addins readily available for this solution.  I know in .Net it's as easy as dropping in a 'detailsview' control...  From the feedback it seems it's a little more detailed in excel.  Perhaps i'll just copy the 26 rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

'By hand' may indeed be easier for just 26 rows of data, but the following process might be useful where there are many more rows (and the requirement is not frequent!):

1. Select data other than headers and Paste Special, Transpose.
2. Select all transposed data and replace `V` with `Column: V`.
3. Select one column at a time and replace `:` with `1:` (repeat for `2:` and `3:`) to suit.
4. Select as before and copy into Word as Text only.
5. Select all and Find what: `^p`, Replace with: `^t^t`, Replace All.
6. Select all, INSERT, Tables - Table, Convert Text to Table... with Number of columns: `1`.

Note that this switches column reference numbers.